# Spark doesn't add date to the SQL WHERE clause

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark

I am trying to understand how Spark loads data from MySQL by reading the MySQL log. But I find that Spark doesn't add date filter to the SQL query it generates where I use the filter() method.

Here is how I load the data in Spark:

```
Properties configProps = new Properties();
// ... properties init
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
spark.read().jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb", "table", configProps)
    .filter("user_id = 1 and date >= \"2019-02-01 00:00:00.000\" and date <= \"2019-02-01 23:59:59.999\"")
    .write().saveAsTable("test_table");
```

What I find it MySQL's log is like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = 1
```

The date is not added to the WHERE clause. Why does that happen? Is Spark trying to load the data of all dates from the table? My table will have millions of records in it but each time only thousands of them are needed.

I have also tried replace filter() with where() but no luck.

Is there any way I can force Spark to use all the criteria I specify in the filter() method?

PS: I didn't find anything on Spark's website describing how Spark works internally. Any books and websites recommended? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your `date` is in correct format? You should also try to change quotation marks in filter for example `.filter("user_id = 1 and date >= '2019-02-01 00:00:00.000'")`. Otherwise you could use filtering in time like this: `.filter(col("date").between("2017-01-01 00:00:00+000", "2017-02-01 00:00:00+000"))`

Comment: @astro_asz sorry, my typos. I have corrected it. Thanks.